# Unable to compile QT Create Quick Application Project

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I am new to QT Creator and I have installed QT Creator 5.6.2 with MinGW 4.9.2 32bit. I have a problem compiling a quick application project as it always shows this error message:

```
Could not create directory "C:\Users\Hello\Documents\Error in " Util.asciify("build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_6_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug")": TypeError: Property 'asciify' of object Core::Internal::UtilsJsExtension(0xb05718) is not a function"
Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.2 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "qmake"
```

Answer (score 12):

By chance I stumbled across the exact same issue today on a native Ubuntu computer and I found the solution here:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59509

"Please go to Preferences > Build & Run > General and click "reset" behind "Default build directory". Looks like this is an incompatibility when using Qt Creator 4.3 without having used Qt Creator 4.2 before, and then going to Qt Creator 4.2 instead."

I thought to share the solution, because it seems to be a quite undocumented issue!

Comment: I had this problem too ! thank you this solved my problem

Answer (score 9):

I am a beginer in QT but it is easy to solve...
Just go to Projects and change the content at Build Directory for a valid directory.
Good Luck