# Qt could not create directory

Tags: android, c++, qt

I am new in Qt platform. I am trying to run and build a project in Qt but I have stumbled upon a bunch errors. I have found solutions to some of them and other I did not. Which leads me to ask you guys this question.
When I build/run my project it is giving me this error:

> Could not create directory "C:\Users\name\Documents\Error in "
>   Util.asciify("build-untitled9-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_2-Debug")":
>   TypeError: Property 'asciify' of object
>   Core::Internal::UtilsJsExtension(0x34d22c8) is not a function" Error
>   while building/deploying project untitled9 (kit: Android for
>   armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.6.2)) When executing step "qmake"

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I met the error too!
You can try this method:

[Tools -> Options -> Build&Run -> General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9OMm.png)

**Then reset the "Default build directory".**

My "Default build directory"  is `"../build-%{CurrentProject:Name}-%{CurrentKit:FileSystemName}-%{CurrentBuild:Name}"`

**Finally**
Restart the QT and create new project. The setting can take effect.

Comment: Yes, restart the qt is the most important step ... I did the above but without restarting, then it couldn't work. Now it's OK !

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found the solution at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569947/unable-to-compile-qt-create-quick-application-project/44328556). this solved my problem.

> Please go to Tools > Options > Build & Run > General and click "reset" behind "Default build directory.