# Why Qt is giving me error about "inability to create directory" of a project?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, frameworks

The thing is I am new to Qt, above at all, I am even more new to using frameworks. It is first time that I am using Qt framework for developing GUI for my end-semester programming project as Electrical Engineering Student.

But after installing Qt v5.6, when I made a project and compiled it then I got this frustrating error.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569947/unable-to-compile-qt-create-quick-application-project?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Yes it solved my problem. But now I am getting new error https://imgur.com/RBJwXZY

Comment: This second error is a link issue, possibly because you miss the `QT += widgets` in your .pro file. Consider asking it in a dedicated post.

Comment: @Adrien  Problem still persists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple:

1. Do not use `<QtModule/QClass>` includes: they hide project misconfiguration and delay errors until linking.
2. After making sure that the `.pro` file contains relevant modules, you must re-run qmake and build the project. Or simply delete the entire build folder: this will force qmake to run again.
3. `QCoreApplication` cannot be used with widgets. Use `QApplication` instead.

Your program can look as follows:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPushButton button("Hello, World!");
  QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, &app, &QCoreApplication::quit);
  button.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

The .pro file is very simple:

```
QT = widgets
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = MyExample
SOURCES = main.cpp
```